NpgSQL DataSourceBuilder compatibility with .NET Framework 4.8 project
I am currently, designing a Revit plugin macro using Revit API, which uses .NET Framework 4.8. Hence my project is in that framework. At the moment I am trying to write certain output parameters, to a PostgreSQL database using NpgSQL. However, when I run my macro, I am getting a type initializer for NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder error prompt from Revit. I was able to test the code in a different framework (.Net 8.0) and it was working fine.
My question is: As I am using a different framework, would I have to use NpgsqlConnectionrather than NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder?
I have a DB_Reading Class that is used to initialize the connection to the database. Where I call it and pass certain parameterized queries in other classes.
using Npgsql;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;


namespace Revit_Plugin_V5
{
    public class DB_Reading
    {
    
        public string Server_Name { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
        public string Database_Name { get; set; }
        public string User_Name { get; set; }  
        public string Password {get; set;} 

        public NpgsqlConnection Connection { get; set; }
        public NpgsqlDataSource dataSource { get; set; }
        private static DB_Reading _instance = null;
        public static DB_Reading Instance()
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _instance = new DB_Reading();
                    
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    
                    throw new Exception("" + ex.Message + " Instance()");
                }
            }

            return (_instance);

        }

        public bool IsConnect()
        {
            if(Connection == null)
            {
                if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Database_Name))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                
                NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder sb = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                sb.Database = Database_Name;
                sb.Host = Server_Name;
                sb.Password = Password;
                sb.Username = User_Name;
                sb.Port = Port;
                try
                {
                    // Connection = new NpgsqlConnection(sb.ToString());
                    // Connection.Open();

                    NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(sb.ToString());
                    dataSource = dataSourceBuilder.Build();
                    Connection = dataSource.OpenConnection();
                    
                    
                    
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception("" + ex.Message + " IsConnect() is the problem");
                }
            }

            return (true);
        }

        public void Close()
        {
        
            Connection.Close();
        }

    }

}


For example in another class I would call the DB_Reading class via:
            var dbCon = DB_Reading.Instance();
            dbCon.Server_Name = "localhost";
            dbCon.Database_Name = "database";
            dbCon.Port = 5432;
            dbCon.User_Name = "user_name";
            dbCon.Password = "password";
            
            if (dbCon.IsConnect()==true)
            {

                string query = "SELECT DISTINCT job_name,job_id FROM Table"; 

                using(var cmd = dbCon.dataSource.CreateCommand(query))
                {
                    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    List<int> parameters = new List<int>();
                    try
                    {
                        while(reader.Read())
                        {
                            
                            string job_name = reader.GetString(0);
                            int job_id = reader.GetInt32(1);
                            
                            job_names.Add(job_name); // public
                            job_ids.Add(job_id); // public
                            job_list.Add(job_name + "-" + job_id.ToString()); // private
                        }

                        reader.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("" + ex.Message + " reader");
                    }

                    
                }
                
            }
            dbCon.Close();
            dbCon.Connection = null;
            
    
       




Make sure you are doing a clean build after changing from Net 8.0 to Net 4.8 so all the intermediate obj files get updated.  Your connection is not completing, it is not the IsConnected that is the problem.   It may be the driver version that is in the connection string that is the issue.  The driver has to be compatible with the Net version you are using.

Oh ok. Just to confirm, would I look at the Nuget packages information to see what version is compatible with my project framework?

Read following : https://www.npgsql.org/doc/compatibility.html#net-frameworknet-coremono

Oh that definitely helps. Thank you!
